# Ruby operator overloading method from block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, dsl

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2. For example i've got class :

```
class Test
  def ==(param)
    # some process
  end

  def bar(param)
    puts "foo bar #{param}"
  end
end
```

I can invoke **bar** method using :

```
Test.new.instance_eval{ bar 'celona' }
```

But i cannot execute **==** method from block like

```
Test.new.instance_eval{ == "foo" }
```

i've got **syntax error, unexpected tEQ**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
class Test
  def ==(param)
    p "You put #{param}"
  end
end

Test.new.instance_eval{|a|  a == "foo" }
=> "You put foo"
```

The solution really depends on your use case.

**Edit** The same holds true for when you instantiate a class.

```
b = Test.new
b == "foo"
=> "You put foo"
```

You can also use `self`

```
Test.new.instance_eval{self == "foo" }
```

I am not entirely sure of the reason, but I would guess that the `==` method required an explicit callee and it can't infer `self`

Comment: thanks for answer, but using Test.new.instance_eval{self == "foo" } i can't invoke like Test.new.instance_eval{bar == "foo" } where bar itself is a method

Comment: That is because bar returns a string.  You are then comparing the string returned by bar to "foo" If you put `self` as the last line in your bar called, then it returns the instance of `test` that you are acting on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Test.new.send("==", "foo")
```